# Online Blender Manual unavailable?

Tags: error, documentation

I'm trying to access the online blender manual, but I can't connect to it from my laptop or phone. It seems that something is wrong with the security settings. I know this isn't the correct place to put this kind of thing, but I haven't seen anything else about it online. I did try the thing mentioned by Andrew Guam [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/ssl-error-how-to-go-around-it/32935ffc-6844-4a2e-9c0f-52ba6b9b9d0d), but it also didn't work. Here's a screenshot of the normal version and IE versions, respectively.
[image: Connection error when using Edge] [image: Connection error in IE mode] Text of normal version:

> The connection for this site is not securedocs.blender.org uses an unsupported protocol.
> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
> Unsupported protocol
> The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

Text of IE version:

> Can’t connect securely to this page
> This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.
> Your TLS security settings aren’t set to the defaults, which could also be causing this error.
> Try this:
> •Go back to the last page

Does anyone know what the cause of this is, or some way around it?
My laptop runs Windows 11 and my phone is an iPhone 12, if it matters.

Comment: "but I haven't seen anything else about it online" - where did you actually look? When I can't reach a site which I usually could earlier, I make a Google search like the one I did yesterday: _"blender.org down?"_, and within seconds I found out "yes, it is down" and a little bit later that there is (was) a DDoS attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DOS attack is currently making Blender servers unreachable for many people, as stated yesterday on Blender Artists Forum

## [DDoS Attack Makes Blender.org Servers Unreachable](https://blenderartists.org/t/ddos-attack-makes-blender-org-servers-unreachable/1493687)

> The [Blender.org](http://blender.org/) 47 infrastructure is currently under a Denial of
> Service attack. As a result, all official Blender sites are currently
> down. The team is aware and is working on a solution.
>
> Be careful when downloading from alternative locations, the [Blender
> Foundation provided](https://mastodon.social/@Blender/111442195348581546) 63 the following list of official mirrors:
>
> - EU: https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/graphics/blender/release/ 188
> - US https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/blender/release/ 225
> - Cn: https://mirrors.aliyun.com/blender/release/ 17
> - Steam: https://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/Blender/ 74
> - Microsoft Store: https://microsoft.com/store/apps/9PP3C07GTVRH 69
> - Source code: https://github.com/blender 67
>
> We will post updates here as they become available.